# How to display wait message while application is working with database?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How to display wait message while my windows application is working with database.

the problem is when i display the message "Please wait..." application does not responds till it completes database operations.

i have simple function which interact with db while it is executing i wanted to display a message like "Please wait..."

But my application should not hang and must respond to user interaction.

this is my function.

```
         public void getReleaseInfo(Label lblDbVersion)
            {
                if (gc.logger.IsInfoEnabled)
                    gc.logger.Info("getReleaseInfo - Method Start");

                string l_sConfigPath = gc.APP_CONFIG_FILE_PATH;
                var element = XDocument.Load(l_sConfigPath).Descendants("configuration").Descendants("connectionStrings");
                if (element != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in element.Elements("add"))
                    {
                        gc.APP_CONNECTIONSTRING = (string)item.Attribute("connectionString");
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    m_oConn = new SqlConnection(gc.APP_CONNECTIONSTRING);
                    m_oConn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter l_oDA = new SqlDataAdapter(gc.SP_GETRELEASEINFO, m_oConn))
                    {
                        l_oDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        using (DataSet l_oDS = new DataSet())
                        {
                            l_oDA.Fill(l_oDS);
                            if (!l_oDS.HasErrors)
                            {
                                if (l_oDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    lblDbVersion.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(l_oDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ReleaseInfo"].ToString()) ? "Release information not available" : l_oDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ReleaseInfo"].ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tsslDbError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lblDbVersion.Text = "iReg Release Information Not Available";
                    tsslDbError.Text = "Unable to connect with iReg Database, Please contact iReg Suppot!";
                    btnBrowse.Enabled = false;
                    btnBackup.Enabled = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (m_oConn != null)
                    {
                        if (m_oConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                            m_oConn.Close();

                        m_oConn.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                if (gc.logger.IsInfoEnabled)
                    gc.logger.Info("getReleaseInfo - Method End");
            }
```

and from here i am calling that function.

```
            try
            {
                lblDbVersion.Text = string.Empty;
                this.tsslDbError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                tsslDbError.Text = "Please wait... While connecting to iReg Database.";
                getReleaseInfo(lblDbVersion);   
                this.tsslDbError.Text = string.Empty;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
                this.tsslDbError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblDbVersion.Text = "iReg Release Information Not Available";
                this.tsslDbError.Text = "Unable to connect with iReg Database, Please contact iReg Suppot!";
                btnBrowse.Enabled = false;
                btnBackup.Enabled = false;
            }
            finally 
            {

            }
            if (gc.logger.IsInfoEnabled)
                gc.logger.Info("btnIregPath_Click - Method End");
        }
```

Comment: If you are using .net 4.5 then you can use async and await to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a Backgroundworker (System.ComponentModel)

your code should be something like this (it's a sample... ;-) not a perfect solution e.g.
if error occurs you'll never see the label populated by the error, but always empty. I think you can understand why. Please note you'll probably get some "unsafe code warnings" trying to change the content of labels created in different threads avoid that managing workerprogess changes).

```
using (BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker())
{
    bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;

    this.tsslDbError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    tsslDbError.Text = "Please wait... While connecting to iReg Database.";
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And for sure you have to add those methods:

```
private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.tsslDbError.Text = string.Empty;
    if (gc.logger.IsInfoEnabled)
        gc.logger.Info("btnIregPath_Click - Method End");
}

private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lblDbVersion.Text = string.Empty;
        getReleaseInfo(lblDbVersion);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.tsslDbError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblDbVersion.Text = "iReg Release Information Not Available";
        this.tsslDbError.Text = "Unable to connect with iReg Database, Please contact iReg Suppot!";
        btnBrowse.Enabled = false;
        btnBackup.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute the database call in a separate thread in order to maintain a responsive UI while the database call is running.

Answer (score 0):

As you know because of the speed of the computers if an error of this kind occurs it will never be displayed with your method because the next error will overwrite the previsous error in milli second, if there is no stop point like messagebox.show or a textbox where the errors is written line by line.

I suggest you to use a log textbox if the error number is not enormous.